# Best practice to store media files in a big web project

Tags: image-processing, subdomain, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a CakePHP 3 project. This project requires many images and pdf files to be uploaded later when project goes live.

At present all images required for design of website is stored in `webroot/img`

Storing images later will make the application size large. I want to keep the application part as clean as possible and store all media files at some other place.

Is it a good practice to store all media files on a separate `subdomain` like `media.website.com` ? Can I upload images to this subdomain with CakePHP ?

Comment: You can use other subdomain. In best practices is to make your sollution easy to deployment and flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Amazon AWS S3 service to store all media files.
It is very fast with low cost.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, but I have no plan to store files on any 3rd party server like Amazon AWS S3. I have to store it on my own service but at some other location outside the application.

Comment: ok, yes..it's a good idea to use a subdomain to store media files and you need to use image compression functionality for large size images.
So that will save your space on a subdomain.